# Access the local machine from inside a docker container with the "localhost" name on Windows 10

Tags: docker

I want to use the chrome-standalone docker image to run my frontend tests :

1. start my environment exposed on the physical machine localhost
2. start a chrome-standalone container capable of calling the physical machine localhost
3. run selenium tests using the chrome-standalone remote web driver

This is actually working fine with the host network_mode (--net="host") on linux machines, but on Windows I keep on getting "localhost refused to connect".

- First I started by creating a new Hyper-V virtual machine with a custom virtual switch connected to External network and running the container in it (powershell commands as admin) :

  ```
  $vmSwitch = Get-VMSwitch -Name 'Custom Virtual Switch'

  $net = Get-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet'

  New-VMSwitch -Name "Custom Virtual Switch" -AllowManagementOS $True -NetAdapterName $net.Name

  docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Custom Virtual Switch" -hyperv-memory 1024 --engine-insecure-registry docker.cirb.lan ChromeDriverVM

  & "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe" env ChromeDriverVM | Invoke-Expression

  docker run -d -P --network="host" -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome
  ```
- Next I tried calling the external physical machine IP, this is working for the first call but after that I'm redirected to localhost and it doesnt work anymore.
- I tried also adding adding "--add-host LOCAL_IP:localhost".
- And finally used the docker.for.win.localhost name, same problem still can't call the physical hosting machine.

Using link won't do it for me, I would have to change some modules I'm not able to change.